# null pointer exception using dom parser in android

Tags: android, xml, dom

i m getting an xml response from server api .while the parsing the xml .i m getting a null pointer exception.below is the xml response and code.i m able to get the single node list but getting an exception "kd.in setHighscore()"

**//xml response**

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">700</int>

Document doc = getDomElement(responseXML);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("int");
    Log.v("node","no of nodes present"+nl.getLength());
     HighestScore kd = new  HighestScore();
      try
        {
      kd.setHighScore( ((Node) nl.item(0)).getNodeValue());  

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
        }
      return kd;
```